# DDoS implication on your network?

Tags: ddos

DDoS attack can be used to infiltrate your network for attackers to try to exploit the machines in the inner network ?

Or it just attack that meant to disrupt the daily operation of a Network.

Comment: disruption in most cases

Answer (score 3):

DDoS stands for 
**D**istributed **D**enial **o**f **S**ervice

The impact for you as the target of such an attack would be a severe disruption of you operational capabilities.

A DDoS attack may be used to hide another attack - maybe on another host - that plans to gain access, but on it's own, this attack will not help an attacker to gain access.

On the other side, some methods (e.g. [fuzzing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing) used by penetration testers (and malicious actors alike) may lead to a Denial of Service on your end.

Answer (score 0):

DDoS can't be used to infiltrate your network but to disrupt operation, and therefore maybe prepare for an attack.
But DDoS itself is not capable to access your (internal) network

Answer (score 0):

A DDoS Attack does affect the uptime rate of your network, it is important that all network pieces are staying up and running, as it is important for commercial websites to not make potential loss, a preventative control can be using load balancing for example to spread the load to other member machines.

Answer (score -1):

On it's own, a DDOS attack will just disrupt your network and prevent devices to work as intended.

However you have to consider two things :

- A DDOS attack may be a symptom of another attack (fuzzing, massive bruteforce, and so on)
- A DDOS may only be a decoy to hide another attack

Comment: This looks to be a copy of the other answer

Comment: You're right it does, sorry I wasn't paying much attention !